# realm with parceler to pass data across activities and services

Tags: android, realm, parceler

I am using [parceler](http://parceler.org/#getting_parceler) with realm to pass data from activity to service.
i have few restrictions of [realm and parceler](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#parceler)

Restrictions

There are some important restrictions to be aware of when using Parceler:

1. If you model contains a RealmList you need to register a special adapter.
2. Once an object has been parcelled, it becomes detached from Realm and at this point behaves like an unmanaged object containing a snapshot of the data.Further changes to this object will not be persisted in Realm

for rule 1 i have register a special adapter for it , but for rule 2 i have a doub that at what point realm got deatched

is it at the time of annoting a class i.e. using

```
@Parcel(value = org.parceler.Parcel.Serialization.BEAN, analyze = { VisitInfo.class })
```

or at the time of unwrapping and wrapping

```
  RequestInfo requestInfo = Parcels.unwrap(intent.getParcelableExtra("visitData"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It becomes an unmanaged copy when you call `Parcels.wrap()` in the first place.

Realm by default expects you to send the primary key of the object over in the intent, and to requery it in the other Activity.